# Images not showing up on FlatList Android with an error "Pool hard cap violation?" in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 25-30 items in my FlatLis but I don't render all of them initially, I am fetching more and more when user reaches the end. After 24-25 images, I am getting this error on some particular android devices and emulators:

`Pool hard cap violation? Hard cap = 150994944 Used size = 150539928 Free size = 0 Request size = 1680000`

This error coming from Image's onError prop.

the invidiual item looks like this;

```
   <Image
                ref={imageRef}
                onError={async (e) => {
                    console.log('IMAGE LOAD error', e.nativeEvent.error);
                }}
                {...props}
                source={source}
                onLoadEnd={onLoadEnd}
                resizeMode="cover"
            />
```

Each image is around 200kb so the size shouldn't be a problem I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using `windowSize` and `removedClippedSubviews` props from `FlatList`. I set `windowSize` to 5 for android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Add option `android:largeHeap="true"` in `<application>` tag of `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file to fix your error:

```xml
<application
  android:largeHeap="true"
  ...
>
  ...
</application>
```